# How to make that it start before everything, after login?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have a file manager in c++ for ubuntu,

How to make that it start before everything, after login

Comment: Put it in "startup programs"

Comment: Why does it need to be started before everything?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways.  The easiest it put it in the user's [.bashrc](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1409419).

Alternatively, here's an example that automatically starts "firefox" for *all* users (courtesy of updating /etc/xdg/autostart):

- http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/09/automatically-startup-applications-for-all-users-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: bashrc will be executed every time user opens terminal emulator and more. It's not what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a call of your program into `~/.xsessionrc`.

Also, you can replace session command in configuration of your login manager. By default in Ubuntu 12.04 this command is placed after `Exec=` in `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` file.